# Glivenko-Cantelli theorem proof

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-explanation

Glivenko-Cantelli theorem states that:

$$\sup_{x\in \Bbb R}|F_n(x)-F(x)|\to 0 \quad\text{almost surely}\,,$$

where $F_n(x)$ is an empirical CDF. There is a [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem#Proof) with a proof for discrete random variable, but I don't really get this line:

$$\sup_{x\in \Bbb R}|F_n(x)-F(x)|\leq \max_{j \in \{1,\ldots,m\}}|F_n (x_j)-F(x_j)| + \frac{1}{m}$$

Could anyone please explain me why that is true?

Comment: In the link the $x_i$ are chosen so that $F(x_i) - F(x_{i-1}) = 1/m$. The inequalities in the  lines above follow from this, the monotonicity of $F$, and the definition of $F_n$. This is what gives your inequality.

Comment: Hi @ElleNajt. Do you know why is it possible to choose $x_i$ such that $F(x_{i})−F(x_{i−1})=1/m$?

Comment: I think they're making the assumption that the CDF is continuous.